# TikZ: variable position arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following example, `twothirdsarrow` allows me to draw a line with an arrow tip at a position that is 0.67 along the line from the first point to the second, as in the source line `\draw[twothirdsarrow...`.

I want to do the same thing but introduce an additional parameter that allows varying that position. My attempt is the definition of `partwayarrow`, which gives an error.

What is wrong with that declaration and how can it be fixed, so that I can then use it in a way such as in the source line `\draw[partwayarrow={`?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    twothirdsarrow/.style 2 args={dashed,semithick, % OK
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.67 with {\arrow{>}, \node[#1]{#2};}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }, 
    partwayarrow/.style 3 args={dashed,semithick,   % GIVES ERROR
        decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}, \node[#2]{#3};}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
  ]
  \draw[twothirdsarrow={right,dashed}{}] (0,1) -- (2,2);        % OK
  \draw[partwayarrow={0.25}{right,dashed}{}] (0,0) -- (1,1);    % NOT WORKING
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(Yes, I'm still grappling with basic syntax of TikZ!)

Comment: You need to say `partwayarrow/.style n args={3}{...},`

Comment: @cis: OK, and I see this in the TikZ/pgf manual, page 988, "Key handler...style 2 args" and  "Key handler...style n args". How peculiar!

Comment: @cis Do you want to post this as an answer? @murray You don't need that comma between `\arrow` and `\node`.